# jQuery AJAX HAndling problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, object

I am trying to create a JavaScript object that will deal with all of my ajax calls instead of making several different ajax handlers have one that does the job for all.

So here's what I have so far

My PHP files that are going to be called within my AJAX Handler are placed in a directory called ajax, the directories within that are named to relate to the pages e.g. the jobs page has its own directory and so on. within these directories I have placed the page relevant PHP files.

so now to my ajax Handler object code:

```
function ajaxHandler(pageName,functionCall){
this.pageName       = pageName;
this.functionCall   = functionCall;

// set functions
this.getPage = getPage;
this.setPage = setPage;
this.getFunctionCall = getFunctionCall;
this.setFunctionCall = setFunctionCall;
this.performAjaxCall = performAjaxCall;
}
// accessor for current page
function getPage(){
    return this.pageName;
}

// accessor for setting the current page
function setPage(page){
    this.pageName = page;
}

// accessor for retrieving the current functionCall
function getFunctionCall(){
    return this.functionCall;
}

// accessor for setting the current function call
function setFunctionCall(func){
    this.functionCall = func;
}

// perform the loaded ajax call
// DATA : must be in the form of JSON
function performAjaxCall(data){
    $.ajax({
       type     : 'POST',
       url      : '/ajax/'+ this.pageName + '/' + this.functionCall + '.php',
       dataType : 'json',
       data     : data,
       success  : function(data){
          return data;
       },
       error    : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          return {"error":true,"msg":thrownError};
       }
    })
 }
```

so with this file called and working fine, apart from when performAjaxCall is called the ajax works perfectly but the data being returned is being seen as undefined I will show you an example

```
function getActiveJobs(initPage){
   var ajh = new ajaxHandler('jobs','getActiveJobs');
   var req = {'page' : 1};
   var data = ajh.performAjaxCall(req);
   alert(data.error);
}
```

The alert returns undefined, I suspect it is because the JavaScript is not waiting for the data to be returned and as such data is not yet defined, but I am unsure I thought I would ask here before leading myself down a blind alley.

Comment: As ajax calls are asynchronous, you would need to specify a callback function to execute on success or error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, JavaScript is not waiting. `performAjaxCall` returns before the response of request is received. But even it were waiting, you cannot return a value from a callback like this:

```
success  : function(data){
      return data;
},
```

You are passing this function to `$.ajax`, so it returns ne value only inside the `$.ajax` function. It does not have any effect on the outer `performAjaxCall` function.

You have to pass another function which will process the data, something like:

```
function performAjaxCall(data, cb){
    $.ajax({
       //...
       success: cb,
       error: cb
    });
 }
```

and

```
function getActiveJobs(initPage){
   var ajh = new ajaxHandler('jobs','getActiveJobs');
   var req = {'page' : 1};
   ajh.performAjaxCall(req, function(data) {
       alert(data.error);
   });
}
```

Comment: thanks thats the answer i needed I have up marked you and I am trying to accept your answer but apparently have to wait another 5 minutes so will do asap :) thanks again