# Return Ajax Data within Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

I am having an issue getting an Ajax Response to be used within an Object.

```
function cart(){
    this.items = [];

    this.addItem = function(item){
        //sorts and adds items to this.items
    }

    this.retrieveCart = function(){
        var itemArray = JSON.parse($.cookie('cartItems'));
        var itemNumbers = [];
        var outData = [];
        for(var i in itemArray){
            itemNumbers.push(i);
        }
        $.post('beta-category-ajax.html', {'get' : itemNumbers.join(",")},
        function(data){
            for(var i in data){
                var currentItemNumber = data[i].I;
                var quantity = itemArray[currentItemNumber];
                data[i].Quantity = quantity;
                outData.push(data[i]);
            }
        });
        this.addItem(outData);
    }
```

I want to be able to run the `this.addItem(Array)` while still using Ajax asynchronously
I saw this thread [jQuery AJAX Handling Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438244/jquery-ajax-handling-problem) but I am not if this applies to me.

Thank you all for the help ahead of time :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declare a javascript object. Then set properties with jQuery and Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287834/declare-a-javascript-object-then-set-properties-with-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/key-concepts/ *"A is for Asynchronous"*

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely clear on what you are asking, but it appears that `this.addItem` wouldn't work the way the code is currently written. The value of `this` changes in the scope of the anonymous function you're passing to $.post. Cache a reference to `this` in `retrieveCart`.

```
this.retrieveCart = function () {
  var self = this;
  ...
  $.post(..., function () { 
    ...
    self.addItem(outData);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just saw the thread [Declare a javascript object. Then set properties with jQuery and Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287834/declare-a-javascript-object-then-set-properties-with-jquery-and-ajax?rq=1) Please Close Mine as a Duplicate

Comment: @4drenaline you should be able to click "Delete"